# Wrapping a file with (function() { … }).call(this) versus a call with simply ()

Tags: javascript

The backbone.js source code uses a function wrapper like this:

```
(function(){
    ...
}).call(this);
```

as seen at http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-185.

Much more often, I've seen the following used instead:

```
(function(){
    ...
})();
```

When does the behavior of these two differ? I was under the impression that they were equivalent, but I assume that there must be a difference given that Backbone uses `.call(this)` instead of the shorter alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, `this` inside of the function will be the `this` from the calling scope.

In the second example, `this` will be `window`.

(As noted by Šime Vidas, it's `undefined` in strict mode, rather than `window`.)

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: One can easily verify this by evaluating `(function() { return (function() { return this; })(); }).call(2)` and noting that it evaluates to `window`, not `2`.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in strict mode it's `undefined` rather than the global object.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas To be honest, I actually did not know that (makes sense though).  Will edit the answer to note that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

With the first `this` is the same in the function as it is in the scope when it is called, for the second this would refer to the window object.